# Desplegar elementos de forma horizontal

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Necesito desplegar los elementos del siguiente `.botton__container` pero de manera **Horizontal**:

```css
.button__container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 40px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.button-radio {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.button-radio--red {
  background: #ff1f1f;
}

.button-radio--blue {
  background: #03a1fc;
}

.button-radio--yellow {
  background: #ffd21f;
}

.button-radio--hidden {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.button__container:hover > .button-radio--hidden {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="button__container">
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--hidden button-radio--yellow">A</div>
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--hidden button-radio--blue">B</div>
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--main button-radio--red">C</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias de antenamo a cualquier ayuda o sugerencia.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema puntual?

Comment: Que se desplegan de manera vertical, pero yo los necesito de manera horizontal (hacia la derecha si es posible)

Comment: Entonces los 3 círculos al fondo verticalmente y a la derecha de forma horizontal ¿cierto?

Comment: Sí, exactamente @BetaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas darle el estilo a `flexbox` para que se horizontal. En tu caso se hace editando las propiedades de css:

```
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
```

Para lo que es `flexbox` siempre tengo este [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (en inglés) a mano, muy útil, conciso y fácil de entender.

```css
.button__container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 40px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.button-radio {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button-radio--red {
  background: #ff1f1f;
}

.button-radio--blue {
  background: #03a1fc;
}

.button-radio--yellow {
  background: #ffd21f;
}

.button-radio--hidden {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.button__container:hover>.button-radio--hidden {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button__container">
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--main button-radio--yellow">A</div>
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--hidden button-radio--blue">B</div>
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--hidden button-radio--red">C</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Update:

Si quieres que salgan para la derecha entonces asigna como elemento padre la `A` por medio de la clase.

Comment: Gracias Fran.
Perdona, ¿cómo los puedo posicionar a la derecha?

Comment: Pero ya están a la derecha.

Comment: No no, pero yo hablo de la posición en que salen..
Es decir, el Grande se posiciona a la izquierda, y que los de adentro salgan hacia la derecha

Comment: Ellos siempre están, para que "saliesen" a la derecha entonces creo que lo mejor sería usar `A` como base, te actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: ¿en el selector `.button-radio--main:hover` se debe modificar también la propiedad `transform` ?... Pregunto porque originalmente tiene el valor: `translateX(-1px) scale(1.05);`

Comment: Vale, muchas gracas Fran!
¿Sabes cómo les puedo dar un poco de espaciado entre los elementos?.. Para que no queden tan pegados?

Comment: La manera más sencilla sería ponerles un margen a los elementos, también existen opciones de espaciado en flexbox que son sumamente útiles. Te actualicé la respuesta para conservar el espaciado original.

Comment: Puedes compartirme algún enlace o recurso donde pueda checar las opciones de espaciado en flexbox porfa

Comment: Están en la respuesta, es el link que dice **tutorial**.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias @Fran!

Comment: Le agregué el margin, de hecho originalmente ya existía un margin pero era solo vertical: `margin: 5px 0;` , lo que hice fue hacerlo general `margin: 5px;`